# CALayer hides its sublayer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-animation

I am trying to add a CALayer as a sublayer of another CALayer. However only the parent layer gets displayed. Here's my code:

```
//display a green square:
CALayer *shipContainer = [CALayer layer];
shipContainer.bounds = CGRectMake(0,0,200,200);
shipContainer.position = CGPointMake(600,500);
shipContainer.borderColor = [UIColor greenColor].CGColor;
shipContainer.borderWidth = 3;

//display a red dot inside the square:    
CALayer *ship1 = [CALayer layer];
ship1.bounds = CGRectMake(0,0,20,20);
ship1.position = CGPointMake(600,500);
ship1.cornerRadius = 10;
ship1.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
[shipContainer addSublayer:ship1];
```

I then call `[self.view.layer addSublayer:shipContainer];` but only the green square is displayed. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Articles/Layers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006082) :

**Position**

> The position property is a CGPoint that specifies the position of the
>   layer relative to its superlayer, and is expressed in the superlayer's
>   coordinate system.

so you need to change

```
ship1.position = CGPointMake(600,500);
```

so that `ship1` can come in visible area. As superlayer has `200,200` as its bounds you need to make position's `x` and `y` less then these values.